# CTRL + CMD + SPACE brings up Characters window instead of Emoji window

Tags: macos, messages, emoji

I'm in Mavericks. When using messages to chat with someone, I used to be able to press CTRL + CMD + SPACE and a little Emoji window would popup and I could choose from an Emoji or type the name of an Emoji to filter the window.

A few days ago, something changed. I don't know what. Now, when I pretty CTRL + CMD + SPACE, a separate "Characters" window pops up in the middle of the screen. It contains Emojis along with hundreds of other type of special characters. It's WAY slower than the emoji window and you can't type the name of emoji's immediately without first clicking into the search field. Anyways, its way worse than it was before.

How do I get the little Emoji window back in Messages? What did I do to change this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you just need to Collapse the Character Viewer by clicking the button next to the search field.

[image]

http://support.apple.com/kb/PH13867

Comment: Good call. Somehow I must have clicked that thing.